# Hide download option video shortcode

Tags: shortcode, videos, video-player

Is there a way to hide the video download option (not all the controls) with the shortcode [video]?

Comment: Please write which theme you're using and also list all the plugins you have installed. It depends if your site is using a custom Video wrapper (like Plyr or VideoJs), or if it's using the native one, built in to the browser. Perhaps add a screenshot of if (so we can see how it looks). Or try in another browser, to see if it's browser-related or not.

Comment: I have just solved the issue by using html instead of the [video] tag. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Glad you solved it. If possible, then it would be awesome if you posted a screenshot and a bit more details in your question - and then added an answer yourself. So it potentially can help others in the future.